# iText - draw arrow at current position

Tags: java, itext

Is there any way I can draw an arrow at the current position or add an arrow to a paragraph like a chunk to get something like:

> This arrow points to the right -> thats it!

How can I draw "->" as arrow like in MS Word **inline**?

EDIT: if someone needs it:

```
public final Font SYMBOL_FONT = new Font(Font.getFamily(BaseFont.SYMBOL));

public Chunk getArrow(final boolean paramLeft) {
    Chunk arrow;

    if (paramLeft) {
        arrow = new Chunk(String.valueOf((char)220), SYMBOL_FONT);
    } else {
        arrow = new Chunk(String.valueOf((char)222), SYMBOL_FONT);
    }

    return arrow;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about something other than the right arrow character (→ or in HTML, `&#8594;`)?

Comment: no, just an arrow, left arrow and right arrow. Does the symbol in a Chunk needs a special encoding or something else?

Comment: *Does the symbol in a Chunk needs a special encoding or something else?* - You need to use a font that contains that symbol.

Comment: @mkl Do you know which font contains those symbols?

Comment: Do you mean one of the *standard 14 fonts*? **Symbol** and **ZapfDingbats** both know different kinds of arrows. You can find their codes in annex *D.5 Symbol Set and Encoding* and *D.6 ZapfDingbats Set and Encoding* of the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Or do you mean other fonts? Many do, many don't.

Comment: no the standard fonts are fine, thank you!